# opendkim milter not launching on proper server socket

Tags: postfix, opendkim, milter

The following error impeded the restart of opendkim

```
× opendkim.service - OpenDKIM Milter
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/opendkim.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2023-04-22 08:00:27 UTC; 2s ago
[...]    Process: 2295 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/opendkim (code=exited, status=78)
opendkim.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=78/CONFIG
```

Attempting to consult the (*unencrypted*, and possibly not updated) documentation, nothing was found regarding `status=78`.
But clearly the milter configurations are incorrect somehow.  `/etc/postfix/main.cf`  defines:

```
# Milter configuration
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
smtpd_milters = local:opendkim/opendkim.sock
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
```

whereas `/etc/opendkim.conf` has

```
Syslog                  yes
SyslogSuccess           yes
LogWhy                  yes

Canonicalization        relaxed/simple
Mode                    sv
SubDomains              no
OversignHeaders         From

UserID                  opendkim
UMask                   007

Socket                  local:/var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock

#Nameservers            127.0.0.1
AutoRestart                     yes
AutoRestartRate                 10/1M
Background                      yes
DNSTimeout                      5
SignatureAlgorithm              rsa-sha256

ExternalIgnoreList      refile:/etc/opendkim/trusted.hosts
InternalHosts           refile:/etc/opendkim/trusted.hosts
KeyTable                refile:/etc/opendkim/key.table
SigningTable            refile:/etc/opendkim/signing.table

PidFile                 /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
# UserID                  opendkim:opendkim
```

I noticed the following:
• the opendkim config originally referenced `ExternalIgnoreList      refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts` whereas the existing file is `/etc/opendkim/trusted.hosts`. This repeats for the whole block.  The whole block was amended to the lower case dot-separaated file names and the service then restarts.

However, emails, while being sent get logged by postfix with:
`warning: connect to Milter service local:opendkim/opendkim.sock: No such file or directory`

```
cd /var/spool/postfix/opendkim
-bash: cd: /var/spool/postfix/opendkim: No such file or directory
```

I also see no pid file in `/var/run/opendkim/`

There are probably a few things wrong here between the postfix `smtpd_milters = local:opendkim/opendkim.sock` configuration and the opendkim `Socket` definition.  What needs to be changed?

**Update**
`warning: connect to Milter service local:opendkim/opendkim.sock: Permission denied` is still in the mail logs, thus that element of configuration is wrong.

changing the setting in `postfix/main.cf` to

```
smtpd_milters = local:/var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock
```

results in:
`warning: connect to Milter service local:/var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock: No such file or directory`.  The existence of `/var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock` is verified.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-70-generic x86_64)

Comment: The `main.cf` use of `local` I didn't see documented in `smtpd`, and in my servers I use the documented `unix`: `smtpd_milters = unix:opendkim/opendkim.sock`, but I don't know if this fixes anything for you.

Comment: Alas, `warning: connect to Milter service unix:/var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock: No such file or directory`

Comment: ...  and `warning: connect to Milter service unix:opendkim/opendkim.sock: Permission denied`  what directory would ` unix:opendkim/` refer to?  that directory does not exists at root level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While that is the path where the socket lies on the system, that is not the path chrooted smtpd instances will see it at:

`smtpd_milters = local:/var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock`

Postfix smtpd wants a path *relative* to the chroot directory, it does not know about the `/var/spool/postfix/` path after start.

`smtpd_milters = unix:opendkim/opendkim.sock`

You can find the details in `/usr/share/doc/postfix/MILTER_README` and `man 5 master`, just quoting the key info here, emphasis mine:

> If the smtpd(8) or cleanup(8) process runs chrooted, an absolute
> pathname is interpreted **relative to the Postfix queue directory**. On
> many systems, local is a synonym for unix

Answer (score 0):

**Partial solution**

`sudo chown opendkim:postfix /var/spool/postfix/opendkim`   was required to give postfix the permissions to create `opendkim.sock`

and while `opendkim.service: Can't open PID file /run/opendkim/opendkim.pid (yet?) after start: Operation not permitted` occured it was temporary

`Started OpenDKIM Milter.` follwoed shortly thereafter and `/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid` was effectively created an `opendkim.pid` owned by root.